# Perl EPIC debugging brings up ActiveState dev kit debugger

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, activestate, epic

Recently I was queued to receive the ActiveState debugger on my machine at work. In the past, I have developed and debugged my Perl code in Eclipse with the PadWalker module installed.

When I run the debugging module now, it tries to launch ActiveState's debugging utility (which I don't have a license for).

I am not extremely proficient with Eclipse, however I did try and look around in the debug launch settings in order to eliminate this, to no avail.

I also removed the reference to ActiveState within my environmental variables, again with no luck.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that ActiveState includes a registry entry that starts up the ActiveState debugger upon calling the debug session.

By going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Perl` in the registry and removing the entry `PERL5DB`, this fixed the problem. I made a backup copy in the `REG_SZ` for the future when I will likely be asked to use the Perl dev kit (PDK)...

I found the fix [here](http://community.activestate.com/faq/restoring-the-native-perl).